# Prove that if $A\setminus B$ is disjoint from $C$ and $x$ in $A$ then $x$ in $B$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, solution-verification, proof-writing

Wanted to see if my proof of this theorem was correct. If it is not, please correct me!

---

**Theorem.** *Suppose that $A \setminus B$ is disjoint from $C$ and $x \in A$. Prove that if $x \in C$ then $x \in B$.*

*Proof.* Suppose $x \in C$. $A \setminus B$ being disjoint from $C$ means that if $x \in A$ then $x \in B$ or $x \in C$. Since $x \in C$ and $x \in A$ then $x \in B$. Therefore, if $x \in C$ then $x \in B$.

---

When it comes to the reason why $A \setminus B$ being disjoint from $C$ means that if $x \in A$ then $x \in B$ or $x \in C$, here is my thought process:
$$\begin{align*}
(A\setminus B) \cap C = \varnothing \iff& \neg \exists x ((x\in A \land x \notin B)\land x\notin C)\\
\iff& \forall x \neg ((x\in A \land x \notin B)\land x\notin C)\\
\iff& \forall x (\neg(x\in A \land x \notin B)\lor x\in C)\\
\iff& \forall x ((x\notin A \lor x \in B)\lor x\in C)\\
\iff& \forall x ((x \in A \rightarrow x \in B) \lor x \in C)
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by saying that your claim is false. If $A\setminus B\cap C=\emptyset,$ then it's not true that $x\in A$ implies that $x\in B$ or $x\in C$. Just take $C$ to be the empty set, and you can see easily that this is false.

Now let's prove the theorem: assume that $x$ is in  $C\cap A.$ Obviously, $x$ is either in $B$ or in $B^c$. Assume that $x\in B^c$. Then $x\in (C\cap A)\cap B^c.$  But $A\cap B^c=A\setminus B.$ Therefore we get that $x\in C\cap (A\cap B^c)=C\cap (A\setminus B).$ But this is empty by assumption and we get a contradiction. Therefore $x$ must lie in $B$.

Finally let's say what is wrong with your proof. Well I'd say that the first mistake is in the first line of your chain of equivalences. You said that $$(A\setminus B)\cap C=\emptyset \longleftrightarrow \lnot\exists x\text{ such that }x\in A \wedge x\not\in B \wedge x\not\in C.$$ But this is not true. The left hand side is empty if and only if there is no $x$ such that $x\in A\wedge x\not\in B\wedge x\in C.$

Comment: Would it be true that $x \in C \rightarrow (x \in A \rightarrow x \in B)$, and since $x \in C$ then $x \in A \rightarrow x \in B$, and it follows that $x \in B$ because $x \in A$?

Comment: If I understood what you mean, yes. $x\in C$ implies that if $x\in A$ then $x\in B$.

Comment: What does the $B^c$ notation mean?

Comment: It is the complement of $B$, so everything that is not in $B$.

Comment: Andreas: $A\setminus B$ means that *if* $x\in A$, then $x\notin B$.